# How do you define a constant in PLT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I declare that a symbol will always stand for a particular value and cannot be changed throughout the execution of the program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't possible in Scheme. And, for all intents and purposes, it's not strictly necessary. Just define the value at the toplevel like a regular variable and then *don't change it*. To help you remember, you can adopt a convention for naming these kinds of constants - I've seen books where toplevel variables are defined with `*stars*` around their name.

In other languages, there is a danger that some library will override the definition you've created. However, Scheme's lexical scoping coupled with PLT's module system ensure this will never happen.

Comment: In Common Lisp, usually *stars* are used for toplevel variables, +plus-signs+ are used for constants.

Comment: I dont program in Lisp and I had always wondered about the * convention. Thanks for clearing it out.

Answer (score 5):

In PLT Scheme, you write your definitions in your own module -- and if your own code is not using `set!', then the binding can never change.  In fact, the compiler uses this to perform various optimizations, so this is not just a convention.

Comment: Nice to see you hear at stackoverflow, sir.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a macro that evaluates to the constant, which would protect you against simple uses of `set!`

```
(define-syntax constant
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((_) 25)))
```

Then you just use `(constant)` everywhere, which is no more typing than *constant *

Answer (score 1):

A really hackish answer that I thought of was to define a reader macro that returns your constant:

```
#lang racket
(current-readtable 
  (make-readtable (current-readtable)
                  #\k 'dispatch-macro (lambda (a b c d e f) 5)))

#k ;; <-- is read as 5
```

It would then be impossible to redefine this (without changing your reader macro):

```
(set! #k 6) ;; <-- error, 5 is not an identifier
```